# Adding multiple columns using CASE statement and '+' but function not adding correctly

Tags: teradatasql

I am trying to add the values of multiple columns together and then derive an indicator (Yes or No) if the summed value is greater or equal to 1. My query is below:

```
select
case when column1 + column2 + column3  >= 1 Then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' end as "Indicator"
from Table_name
```

The results that I get returned in the Indicator column are all 'No' but I know for a fact that some of the columns that are added have values greater than 1 so I should get some 'Yes' values. Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are any of the values NULL (in which case the sum would also become NULL)?

Comment: yes there are some null values contained in the columns. Any advice on making this query work despite the nulls?

Comment: You could use nested CASE expressions or maybe just apply Teradata-specific `ZeroIfNull` function to each of the individual columns, then sum.

Comment: thanks Fred! applying the ZeroIFNull function worked